# Python - Multiprocessing on a Pandas Dataframe with different functions

Tags: python, pandas, performance, multiprocessing

My input dataframe is analysed by three different user-defined operations - **op1, op2, op3**. Running these operations in sequence is inefficient as they're independent of each other. All three of them can be run in parallel, as they only read the input dataframe, and do not write anything to it.

I tried using Python `multiprocessing` module to enhance my performance. So, I converted the three operations into functions and implemented them through `apply_async` :

```
def calculate(func, args):
   func(args) # Execute function on DataFrame

def analyze(operations, df):
  tasks = [(op, df) for op in operations]
  with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = [pool.apply_async(calculate, t) for t in tasks] # Pass Functor and DataFrame as arguments
        for r in results:
            r.get()
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

operations = [op1, op2, op3]
analyze(operations, df)
```

Theoretically, I assumed I would get a **3x** improvement in performance since now all three operations were running in parallel. However, I observed only a **1.5x** improvement in performance. Can someone help me understand why is it so? Is my implementation wrong? or is there any other way to achieve the **3x** performance?

Comment: You will not get the desired 3x performance, because the processor still needs to run all three processes, but you will significantly improve your runtime. I suggest you read more about how multiprocessing works. Here is something about pool/processes that shows that 3x performance is not going to happen. https://www.ellicium.com/python-multiprocessing-pool-process/

Comment: Each subprocess reads the dataframe from disk? They'll all have to wait on the disk (or disk cache) and do the original dataframe load code, which "unprallelizes" the code. This isn't necessarily bad, especially on Windows, but you may save a bit of time on linux/mac if you read the df before creating the pool. And the result needs to be serialzied / deserialzed in the parent, so keep that small if you cna.

Comment: @tdelaney I've already read the CSV file in a dataframe at the parent, then pass the dataframe to the functions. Is there any way, by chance, that we can avoid this sequential lookup in disk? I assume the data is not being copied to the three processes to improve performance, right?

Comment: @nagyl Thanks for sharing the link. So, from the link I understand that if the no.of tasks/operations are small and if there's I/O latency, it's better to use ```Process``` than ```Pool``` ?

Comment: @saransky I haven't tested it, the article states that, an I would believe what they say, therefore I suggest you use Process, since you do io operations, and you have only 3 tasks. May I write an answer with this solution to be accepted?

Comment: @nagyl. Sure, Let's check with ```Processes``` and see.

Comment: @saransky ok, let me know! It won't be the desired 3x performance, but maybe a little bit faster, than Pool. Maybe nothing significant, since you have only 3 processes.

Comment: @nagyl. Lets' try...